# database connection in node.js, multiple script files

Tags: mysql, node.js

How can I connect these two files  an error connection not defined is occurring
ReferenceError: connection is not defined

I am using MySQL database I have cut many of my code the only problem is in connecting these two files

```
// router file
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


  // form for note creation
  router.get('/create', (req, res) => {
    res.render('notes/create')
  })
  
  // creating note
  router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let note = {heading:req.body.heading, body:req.body.body};
    const sql = 'INSERT INTO note SET ?';
    connection.query(sql,note, (err, rows) => {
      if (err)
      res.send(err);
      else
      res.redirect(`/notes`)
    });
  })
  module.exports = router;
```

```
// main app file

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const note = require('./routes/note');


const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'pass1',
  database: 'notetakingapp',
  multipleStatements: true
})

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Database Connected')
})
app.use('/notes', note)

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('on port 3000')
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't pass the connection variable so it's normal that it's not defined in other files. You can add code in app file like this

```
app.set('connection', connection)
```

and then in the other files

```
const connection = req.app.get('connection')
```